# Hatching my egg in a foreign game and trading back for Masuda Method?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I want to start breeding for a certain shiny Pokémon. One way to go about it would be to obtain another Pokémon of the same species but opposite gender and a different language tag. But on top of that I want my shiny to, possibly, have competitive stats so I want the foreign Pokémon to have similar stats to my own.

One way I thought of doing this would be to pre-hatch an egg of mine that would hatch with the stats I'm looking for, ask someone to hatch it in their foreign game and then tradeback. As far as I know the egg would hatch with the new owner's OT, but I don't know if it gets the foreign language tag - if it could be used for the Masuda Method when traded back.

I've looked it up in Bulbapedia and Google but the answers I found were unclear or offered no proof.

Would this work, or do I need a 100% foreign Pokémon for the Masuda Method?

Comment: hatching while one of pokemon holding Destiny Knot will inherit five parents IVs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pokemon would be hatched in for foreign's game will have his language tag. As soon as an egg is created all its stats will be set(IVs, Natures, Ability e.g.).

But there is an easier way to start with the Masuda method. Since it only requires a pokemon from a different region. (Asian is the most common used). And there are a lot of Facebook groups which will give you a free 6IV Asian Ditto with Destiny Knot. I am in one of those groups myself.

Secondly. And as a piece of advice. Recently there is a new Discovery regarding Shiny Breeding with the Masuda Method. Which will result in the faster breeding of shinies. You can find the explanation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et9RT.png)
It explains that, in Sun & Moon. The result of the egg(it being shiny or not) is already set within the game as you start breeding. With this knowledge you can chain hatch Magikarps(Pokemon with the least amounts of steps required to hatch) and as soon as you hatch a shiny you can soft reset and the X egg(the number that hatched the shiny Magikarp) will now hatch a shiny X pokemon.

Ofcourse there are some exceptions(genderless or 100%ratio gender pokemon)

Comment: I can link you to the facebook group. Since im not sure im allowed to link it here.

Comment: I would prefer not to use hacked Dittos, I'm not against it but for now I want to keep it legit. I've read that people use Magikarps to find their RNG state, but I didn't know about swap breeding. Very useful, thanks. But, back to my question, all stats are determined when the egg is created, not when hatched, but not the language tag, is that it? Are you sure it can be used for Masuda?

Comment: You can find several Ditto giveaways also on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokeMoonSun/).

Comment: @aslg The language tag is also created. Since its already considered "born" to the game. It doesn't really matter who hatches it. Also, there is a difference between "legal" and "legit" in pokemon. The Ditto you get might not be legit(The Pokemon was obtained in a legitimate copy of the game, EV trained legitimately, and is not hacked in any way) but it is Legal(The Pokemon may have been hacked, but everything about it is obtainable by legit means)which, to me is the most important.

Comment: @Taacoo I see. Then it probably doesn't trigger the Masuda Method, and I would need someone else to trade their own bred Pokémon instead. Thank you.

Comment: @aslg check my edit tho. Might change your view on the Ditto.

Wonder Trade is also an amazing place to get lots of Foreign pokemon.

Comment: @Taacoo The problem with wonder trade is that I'm looking for Pokémon with specific stats and more importantly specific balls (apriballs,beast ball) and nature. Of course, the 6IV Ditto would be the easiest way. I actually have a 6IV Ditto in Gen 6 obtained from reddit. As I said, I'm not against it. It's just I still have hopes of getting good Dittos from SOS chains, so until I give up I won't get a hacked 6IV Ditto. Thanks though.

Comment: @aslg Got some breejects if you are interested ;') [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1grGFC-zyfeWXY_kK2G7TF72NM7wWEvQEAFULqfjOYPw)

Comment: @Taacoo I thought the stats were determined _before_ the egg was found/created not at the time of being found/created? (see [Time Machine Method](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/696959-pokemon-x/67960441) from XY)

Comment: @PhilD. Check the link i used in my answer. There it explains that the game determines the IV heritage and everything else is set. Even after resetting and hatching different pokemon you'll find out that the IV heritage between father and mother is exactly the same(Under specific circumstances, like the mother/father being a ditto and just swapping out the non-ditto after you reset it)

Comment: @Taacoo Your link describes the mechanics in the time machine method I linked, though your wording in the answer suggests that the stats are set when the egg is _found_. I'm just clarifying this point. If the stats were set when the egg is found as you say, then resetting to a point before the egg is found would result in different stats being generated, which is not what happens. Seems like a miss communication, sorry.